# Symfony 3.4 - Circular reference detected for service

Tags: php, symfony, exception, doctrine-orm

I'm migrating my project from Symfony 2.7 to 3.4 and I'm facing a problem by executing some Doctrine fixtures. As title says, I get this error

```
Error thrown while running command "doctrine:fixtures:load --append". Message: "Circular reference detected for service "service_2", path: "service_2"." ["error" => Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException { …},"command" => "doctrine:fixtures:load --append","message" => "Circular reference detected for service "service_2", path: "service_2"."] []
```

when I try to get a service using the service container which is already injected in another taken service. The scenario looks like the following:

```
service_1:
  class: Acme\BusinessBundle\ServiceOne
  arguments: ["@service_2"]
  public: true
  tags:
    - { name: monolog.logger, channel: s1 }

service_2:
  class: Acme\BusinessBundle\ServiceTwo
  arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", "@logger"]
  public: true
  tags:
    - { name: monolog.logger, channel: s2 }
```

Then in fixtures I just do

```
$s1 = $this->container->get('service_1');
$s2 = $this->container->get('service_2');
```

to get the exception.

But the very strange thing is that exception comes the second time I get `service_2`. So basically in the first fixture I get both services without any problem but as soon as the second fixture starts and `$s2` is created I get the `ServiceCircularReferenceException` (checked using xdebug). Of course I had no problems with Symfony 2.7.

Then why I don't get any exception the first time? Why I get it the second time? Any idea?

Comment: this lines which file? `$s1 = $this->container->get('service_1');
$s2 = $this->container->get('service_2');` or  did you take service_1 into service_2 class?

Comment: All fixtures are located at `BusinessBundle/DataFixtures/ORM`

Answer (score -1):

Pass the whole container to the services and then get the required service within.
This has happened to me several times and I have been always able to fix it changing the dependency injection.

Comment: I know, I could even create a getter in `ServiceOne` to get `ServiceTwo` but actually I can't figure out why at first fixture it works and then from second one it doesn't..

Comment: More info here https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2347 From the second comment "The issue is that each service requires the other one to be created before itself being created."

Comment: I don't think that's my case: `ServiceTwo` doesn't need `ServiceOne` - only `ServiceOne` needs `ServiceTwo`.

Comment: The times that this has happened to me, the service causing the loop was not the ones that I created but some other standard service that is used widely in the app. Twig or Doctrine for instance.

Comment: I thought the same but still I can't understand why it works the first time. It happened again also to me, but it didn't work at all while this time it seems to work partially..

Comment: It's worth to note that if you pass down the container, you still can't access the conflicting service in the constructor - as that causes the same error. You have to defer accessing the service to another method.